# redirecting from facebook link to my mobile app (ionic)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building an app where users can post links to facebook. Basically they can post a text (status)/photo to facebook and what I want to do is, when someone click that status/photo in facebook, it should be open up in my mobile app (which already installed in the users mobile)

So far I've red some things about linking with html5 tags, but the problem is I cannot do that in a facebook post.

How can I archive this with `ionic` (Im a web developer and pretty new to mobile development and cannot get my head around with this ;)

any help would be much appreciated

## EDIT - (updated the question with sample workflow)

Consider following scenario

- user uploads a photo in the mobile app
- user post the same photo to facebook
- when someone click that photo on facebook, it should direct to
  that users mobile app and open the photo in the mobile app

Comment: So you are saying that a text message will be posted inside facebook app and then if user select/tap a specific word(s) of that text then it will open your app?

Comment: @AAhad, thanks for the comment, yes.. and please check my question as I updated it with a sample workflow

Comment: Would something like this work for you?: http://mcgivery.com/using-custom-url-schemes-ionic-framework-app/ It allows you to use a custom URL scheme so when a device opens the link, it will open your app instead of the URL.

Comment: @NicRaboy, that is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot. If you could post this as an answer, I could accept it :), thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the original posters request, my comment turned out to be the answer.

http://mcgivery.com/using-custom-url-schemes-ionic-framework-app/

The above tutorial will explain how to create a custom URL scheme so when the device opens a link, it will open the application instead of the browser.

Comment: I follow your tutorial. When I generate the url from the easyhyperlinks.com. When I click app is opening but can not alert the received url. wondering that my method is executing or not? Could you please help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

According to your needs i think this plugin is helping you (http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.ccsoft.plugin.cordovafacebook).
Its used one of our projects and its working fine for us, but integration with facebook  is little bit complex (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/).You need to setup a facebook application (https://developers.facebook.com/) to achive this.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'm using `cordovafacebook` for login to my app. But what I want now is to link from `facebook` to my app. Please refer my question as I updated it with a sample workflow

Comment: What you mean second thing in your work flow?its like the share feature that means if user clicks that photo it automatically shared his timeline am I right?